# How to make SQL request to get table of counted keywords?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to make a single SQL request like this:

```
SELECT genres, count(*) FROM books WHERE genres LIKE 'Fiction%'
```

But I need to use many keyword like 'Nonfiction%', 'Historical' ect. The output should be a table:

```
Fiction           8654
Nonfiction        6543
Historical        2344
```

What SQL request I have to use to get this result?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data.

Comment: U need to Group By them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you can just do:

```
SELECT genres, count(*)
FROM books 
GROUP BY genres;
```

In fact, you *could* just do this if you had a table called `BookGenres` with one row per book and per genre.  That is the right way to store this data.

In this case you appear to be looking only for the first genre in the list.  You can use `case`:

```
select (case when genres like 'Fiction%' then 'Fiction'
             when genres like 'Nonfiction%' then 'Nonfiction'
             when genres like 'Historical%' then 'Historical'
             else 'Other'
        end) as genre, count(*)
from books
group by (case when genres like 'Fiction%' then 'Fiction'
               when genres like 'Nonfiction%' then 'Nonfiction'
               when genres like 'Historical%' then 'Historical'
               else 'Other'
          end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use group by

```
 SELECT genres, count(*) 
 FROM books
 GROUP BY genres
```

or for a set of values

```
 SELECT genres, count(*) 
 FROM books
 WHERE genres in ( 'Fiction', 'Nonfiction', 'Historical')
 GROUP BY genres
```